# How can I limit the height of a SwiftUI Picker on macOS

Tags: swiftui, picker

How can I limit the height of a SwiftUI Picker on macOS.  Setting the frame height appears to only affect the popup button and no the frame within which the picker options are presented.

Comment: This is default macOS behaviour for any menu. By AHIG you should not put in menu too many items, if such possible Apple recommends to use other controls, like List, etc.

Comment: Hmm so then I will have to create a custom popup list - is there such a thing in SwiftUI?